# What is some good intuition for being parallel or Lie derivative is zero?

Tags: differential-geometry

I would like to know, if my unterstanding of the difference between  parallelness and zero Lie derivative so far are accurate: \
1.
Consider a Riemannian manifold $M$.
My understanding of $L_vT=0$ for some tensor field $T$ and $L_v$ being the Lie derivative goes as follows: The condition $L_vT=0$ means that $T$ does not change by moving infinitesimally along the geodesic defined by $v$, that is its components in any coordinate system stay the same. This especially implies that the tensor is constant along geodesics $\gamma$, if we have $L_{\dot\gamma}T=0$ along $\gamma$. \
\
2. Now consider the notion of being parallel: My understanding of $\nabla  T=0$ for $\nabla$ being the Levi-Civita connection is, that then you get the same value if you plug into $T$ the parallel transports of some vectors along a curve as if you plug into it the initial vectors. \
\
Is this intuition accurate, or can you tell me, what the right understanding of the difference between parallelness and zero Lie derivative is?

Comment: The Lie derivative does not require a Riemannian structure or a connection, so what geodesics are you thinking about in your part 1?

Comment: Also, you may wish to look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/ for some explanations

Comment: @Yuri Vyatkin: Thank you very much. Now I see that in fact my understanding of these notions was a bit flawed and it is better now.