# Exist Contravariant derivative?

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, definition, tensors

I'm confused about the index representation, If the index up represents a contravariant tensor I can do this with the derivative and get it contravariant derivative?Or when it is said that, it is covariant or contravariant by "essence"(before the contravariant and covariant formulation like the gradient Which is  transformed covariant).

I can't get an image because I don't have a score or whatever then I'll try to write,

(Contravariant)  $T^{i'}=\dfrac{\partial x^{i'}}{\partial x_j}T^j$

(covariant).       $V_{i'}=\dfrac{\partial x^j}{\partial x^{i'}}V_j$

Then $g^{ij}\partial_j=\partial^i$, I can transformed it contravariant, For it has index above, But the derivative is always covariant, im confused, what is $\partial ^j$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  This thread might answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908008/why-isnt-there-a-contravariant-derivative-or-why-are-all-derivatives-covarian?rq=1

Comment: The answer by SSD in this [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1908008/why-isnt-there-a-contravariant-derivative-or-why-are-all-derivatives-covarian?noredirect=1&lq=1) sums it up. There are contravariant and covariant tensors (index up index down) *but* there is *only* a covariant derivative often denoted by $\nabla\,.$ You are rightfully confused now because $\nabla^\mu V^\nu$ is a contravariant rank 2 tensor and $\nabla_\mu V_\nu$ a covariant one. It cannot be helped. The nomenclature is not ideal. It works better to just worry about when an index is up or down.

Comment: I deleted  the one I had sent now, if you could answer it? if The derivative is always covariant which is ∂^μ That transform contravariant , and what the metric tensor does by lowering or lifting the Indices, because from what I've seen index above are transformed contravariant, And it is said that derivatives are transformed covariantly, then I ask again what it is ∂^μ

Comment: I will write a detailed answer. By 'covariant/contravariant transform' of a derivative do you mean by the Lorentz transformation? It would help if you use more formulas ([MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  is teriffic) and/or cite your references.

Comment: I still do not know how to mess with mathjax, not necessarily lorentz  transformation, a vector with index up is said contravariant, And it also transform contravariant , and I think I can not show image yet, but This appears in several videos of tensors like in the" khan ",That's what it says, but if we use the metric tensor we can lower indexes, and it left me confused, I don't know if it's the notation but I'm confused about, because the transformations are according to the index and follows this structure to the derivative, so if we apply the metric tensor what happened,contravariant?

Comment: I modified it, now you understand what I didn't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is -as we know- a *covariant derivative* but **not** a contravariant one. A *vector* with upper/lower index is called *contravariant/covariant*, and -as we know- indices are raised/lowered by the metric: $V^\mu=g^{\mu\nu}V_\nu\,.$ This works for the *partial* derivative as well: $\partial^\mu=g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu\,$ and also for the *covariant* derivative $\nabla^\mu=g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\nu\,.$  There is a clash in the nomenclature: $V^\mu$ is a called contravariant vector, but $\partial^\mu,\nabla^\mu$ are **not** called contravariant derivatives.
An acceptable name for $\nabla^\mu$ is *covariant* derivative with an upper index.

The covariant derivative is related to the partial derivative by
$$
\nabla_\mu V^\nu=\partial_\mu V^\nu+\Gamma^\nu_{\mu\lambda}V^\lambda
$$
([Carroll](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9712019.pdf) (2.19) on p. 45, (3.2) on p. 56) and we have the transformation laws
$$
V^{\nu'}=\frac{\partial x^{\nu'}}{\partial x^{\nu}} V^\nu\,,\quad\quad
\nabla_{\mu'}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}} \nabla_\mu\,,\quad\quad
\nabla_{\mu'}V^{\nu'}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu'}}{\partial x^{\nu}}\nabla_\mu V^\nu\,.
$$
Because the primed $\partial x^{\nu'}$ is in the numerator of the first law this is called a *contravariant* transformation. Likewise, the second law is a *covariant* transformation. It is very instructive to work this out explicitly by looking at a Lorentz transformation. The third law is a combination of the first and second law. It is neither covariant nor contravariant (rather mixed) **but**: because the derivatives operator $\nabla$ can be pulled through the transformation
$$
\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\mu'}}\frac{\partial x^{\nu'}}{\partial x^{\nu}}
$$
it acts as if that term was a constant. The plain partial derivative can't do that unless the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma$ are all zero (no curvature). This invariance of $\nabla$ is the reason why it is called (somehow unfortunately) *covariant* derivative. Some people prefer to call it *invariant* derivative instead. Other people today avoid to call $V_\mu$ covariant, resp. $V^\mu$ contravariant, or are just happy with the understanding that it tells where the index is sitting.

[This link](http://einsteinrelativelyeasy.com/index.php/dictionary/25-christoffel-symbol), or for example, H. Weyl's book Space Time Matter give some intuition and historical background about these nomenclatures.

Comment: Thank you bro :)

Comment: You are welcome. I suggested a few edits that show how simple MathJax really is. Also: please mark my answer as being accepted.